# How to change IDE in Projucer

Tags: ide, juce

So I wanted to make a Vst plugin with Projucer but I would like to use my Eclipse IDE instead of Visual Studio. Is this possible or do I have to use visual studio only. Thanks! (Sorry if this is a bad question or is formatted wrong. I don't really know how to use this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Projucer doesn't have an exporter for Eclipse. On Windows, your only options are Visual Studio or Code Blocks.

Check out https://docs.juce.com/master/tutorial_new_projucer_project.html for more info!